# Converting a character to a Date Time format in R

Tags: r, datetime, posix

Don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Am trying to convert a character to a POSIXct date format and getting a null. Here is some sample code:

```
as.POSIXct(strptime("29-MAR-2015 01:14:32", format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

which gives me a NA.

The previous date was in March. If I switch the date to April, and repeat the same process, this is the result I get::

```
as.POSIXct(strptime("29-APR-2015 01:14:32", format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

I get: "2015-04-29 01:14:32 IST"

Why does this conversion work for the March date, but not the April date?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error.  Perhaps check `?Sys.setlocale`

Comment: Turns out it has something to do with the time zone and all I had to do was set the time zone to the country that the data is from. Sorry for the stupidity on my part, was in a rush

Comment: @LorcanTreanor Exactly! You posted that comment right about when I answered. You got it. In general, use `GMT` when in doubt – e.g., if you're processing data from all over the world, and just need to clean up some date formats (e.g., actual time zone doesn't matter), you can rely on GMT to avoid this problem. I think this is a good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `strptime`. E.g., try:

```
as.POSIXct("29-APR-2015 01:14:32", format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

> [1] "2015-04-29 01:14:32 EDT"

Of course, I'm in different time zone.

One thing to keep in mind, is that certain times don't exist in certain time zones due to "daylight savings time" and the like – for example, clocks will "leap" forward or backwards 1 hour; the latter case isn't problematic in your case (but confusing b/c an hour is repeated); the previous case produces a problem because an hour is skipped!

How to solve? Specify a time zone that doesn't have daylight savings time. E.g., GMT:

```
as.POSIXct("29-MAR-2015 01:14:32", format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

> [1] "2015-03-29 01:14:32 GMT"

Note: I can't reproduce your `IST` time zone, so this is really just my best guess. Try using `tz="GMT"`, or specify the *actual* time zone of the date (rather than relying on local time zone), and that should help!

Also explains why others can't reproduce easily.